# Viewing Serialized Hash Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I am trying to build a default checklist for my application by serializing a hash. I don't know how to pull the information in my setup_checklist hash to my views. Any help is appreciated.

Here is my user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  serialize :checklist, Hash

  before_create :setup_checklist

  private

  def setup_checklist
    self.checklist = {
      "Organize Your Finances" => false,
      "Approval Letter" => false,
      "Get a Real Estate Agent and look for houses" => false,
      "Find lawyer" => false,
      "Get the mortgage" => false,
      "Apprisal and inspection" => false,
      "Close the deal" => false
    }
  end
end
```

my view.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :checklist do |f| %>
  <%= f.check_box :checklist %>
<% end %>
```

I know I am not even close but a steer in the right direction would be great

Answer (score 0):

To display checkboxes from a hash, you need to iterate the hash and create a checkbox for each element; for example:

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <% @user.checklist.each do |key, value| %>
    <%= f.check_box key %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the prettiest, but this seems to be working for me

view.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :checklist do |c| %>
    <% @user.checklist.each do |todo, completed| %>
      <%= c.check_box todo %>&nbsp;<%= c.label todo %><br />
    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

and then in the controller

```
def update
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @user.checklist.each do |todo, completed|
    @user.checklist[todo] = params[:user][:checklist][todo] == "1"
  end
  @user.save

  redirect_to action: :show, id: params[:id]
end
```

you could, of course, move that controller code into something like an `update_checklist` method on your model or refactor however works for you, but this should get you started.

If you use strong params, you'll need to permit each possible checklist value and it'll set them to '0' or '1' instead of true or false, but the controller could be

```
    @user.update(params.required(:user).permit(checklist: ["Organize Your Finances", ...]))
```